# passing objects between Spring MVC Controller and model

Tags: spring

I am new to Spring MVC. I have created a controller like this and a model is a POJO. When I build my application, it gives me the error:

Controller:

```
import java.io.IOException;




import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.apache.commons.lang.StringUtils;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;


import com.model.dto.BillingContactDto;


/**
 * The Class BillingController.
 */
@Controller
public class BillingController extends BillingBaseFormController {

    /** The log. */
    private static final Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(BillingController.class);


    //model class
    private BillingContactDto billingContactDto;
       //this is how I believe I should link both of them
       @ModelAttribute("emp")
        public BillingContactDto getEmployee(@RequestParam("empdId") Long id) {
            // Get employee using empId from DB
            return  billingContactDto;
        }

        @RequestMapping(value = "/showEmpDetail", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showEmpDetails()  {
            return "showEmpDetail";
        }
```

error

```
[ERROR] C:\src\billing\web\src\main\java\com\billing\webapp\controller\company\BillingController.java:[142,12] error: cannot find symbol.
```

I need some guidance as to where I am going wrong.
Thanks in advance

Comment: please post full error message

Comment: Have you looked up what a `cannot find symbol` indicates?

Comment: which line is 142 of BillingController?

Comment: public BillingContactDto getEmployee(@RequestParam("empdId") Long id) {